# How to add module to admin/config page?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I'm working on a module in Drupal 7. I've added a hook_menu implementation:

```
$items['admin/config/content/mymodule'] = [
  'title'            => 'MyModule',
  'description'      => 'Configure MyModule settings.',
  'page callback'    => 'mymodule_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => ['mymodule_admin_settings'],
  'file'             => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
  'access arguments' => ['administer mymodule'],
  'menu_name'        => 'mymodule',
];
```

...and a configure line to mymodule.info:

```
configure = admin/config/content/mymodule
```

A *Configure* link for MyModule now appears the **admin/modules** page, but how can I also have the module listed on the **admin/config** page? Or is the **admin/config** page reserved for only core modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the code of [system_admin_config_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_admin_config_page/7), which is page callback for admin/config, I notice it contains the following lines:

```
if ($admin = db_query("SELECT menu_name, mlid FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path = 'admin/config' AND module = 'system'")->fetchAssoc()) {
  $result = db_query("
    SELECT m.*, ml.*
    FROM {menu_links} ml
    INNER JOIN {menu_router} m ON ml.router_path = m.path
    WHERE ml.link_path != 'admin/help' AND menu_name = :menu_name AND ml.plid = :mlid AND hidden = 0", $admin, array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  foreach ($result as $item) {
    _menu_link_translate($item);
    if (!$item['access']) {
      continue;
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

The first query select the menu_name field for the menu associated with the path admin/config, which by default is management; the second query select all the menus that have the same value for menu_name, and whose parent is admin/config.

As your menu uses a different value for menu_name, it is not selected from the second query, and it is not show in the admin/config page.

Answer (score 24):

If you do it like this, with the system.module callback for the parent item, you get the nice listing page when you visit 'admin/config/mymodule'

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {

  $items = [];

  $items['admin/config/mymodule'] = [
    'title'            => 'My configuration section',
    'description'      => 'This is the parent item',
    'position'         => 'left',
    'weight'           => -100,
    'page callback'    => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments' => ['administer site configuration'],
    'file'             => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path'        => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
  ];

  // Need at least one child item before your section will appear.
  $items['admin/config/mymodule/item'] = [
    'title'            => 'First item',
    'description'      => 'This is the first child item in the section',
    'page callback'    => 'mymodule_item_callback',
    'access arguments' => ['administer site configuration'],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you'll need to disable and enable the module for the menu changes to take effect.

Comment: @jevon: clearing the (menu) cache is adequate to see the changes.

Comment: menu cache can be cleared using drush at command line using `drush cc menu` - ref: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/58621/1082

Answer (score 3):

Remove the 'menu_name' part, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this too on the config page.  The only way I was able to do add the link to the config page was to declare two menu items like so, with the parent link at 'admin/config/module' and a child link at 'admin/config/module/manage'.

```
  $items['admin/config/whh-maps'] = array(
    'title' => 'World Hiphop configuration',
    'description' => 'Allows administrators to configure maps for WHH.',
    'position' => 'left',
    'weight' => -30,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('whh_maps_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer whh maps'),
    'file' => 'whh_maps.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/config/whh-maps/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage countries',
    'description' => 'Allows admins to edit country information',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('whh_maps_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer whh maps'),
    'file' => 'whh_maps.admin.inc',
    'weight' => -10,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$items['admin/config/user-interface/mymodule'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'description' => 'description',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_admin_function'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
);

$items['admin/config/user-interface/mymodule/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'description' => 'description',
    'weight' => -10,
);
return $items;
```

this worked for me.
I was actually struggling for about half an hour until I realized I wasn't returning $items....I always seem to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function notification_menu() {

  $items = [];

  $items['admin/customize'] = [
    'title'            => 'Send Comment notifications',
    'discription'      => 'Admin will send notification to user about updates',
    'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => ['notification_form'],
    'access arguments' => ['access adminstration page'],
    'access callback'  => TRUE,
  ];

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Custom form.
 */
function notification_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['send_mail_to'] = [
    '#title'         => 'Send Mail To',
    '#discription'   => 'To whom you want to send form',
    '#size'          => 40,
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#required'      => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('send_mail_to'),
  ];

  //here the admin can wite subject for the mail.
  $form['mail_subject'] = [
    '#title'         => 'Subject',
    '#discription'   => 'the purpous of this mail',
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#size'          => 40,
    '#maxlenght'     => 120,
    '#required'      => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('mail_subject'),
  ];

  $form['mail_body'] = [
    '#title'         => 'Body',
    '#discription'   => 'the body of your mail.',
    '#type'          => 'textarea',
    '#row'           => 10,
    '#columns'       => 40,
    '#required'      => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('mail_body'),
  ];

  $form['mail_bcc'] = [
    '#title' => 'BCC this mail to all',
    '#type'  => 'checkbox',

  ];

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it doesn't say why the OP is not seeing their module listed in the admin page; plus, code-only answers are not much helpful. (Check the code: You have some typos.)