# Change the code in the module from the front end of drupal

Tags: 7

I have created my custom module. Can i edit my module from the from end of drupal rather then going to backend and editing the module. Is there any module for this purpose?

Comment: Are you talking something similar to the way WP lets you edit theme and plugin files from the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a module for this, but this thread begins to touch on how to create your own module admin page. 
[How to add module to admin/config page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/how-to-add-module-to-admin-config-page-in-drupal-7)