# How Generate Configure button ? (Module Page)

Tags: 7

What hook or how do I generate the configure button in the module page?

I'm trying to have the operation button that user click on the module page to take them to the configuration page.

If someone can provide me good resource or an example I will appreciated.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to generated.

[image]

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/how-to-add-module-to-admin-config-page-in-drupal-7

Comment: refer this link for more understanding https://www.drupal.org/node/1111212

Comment: you are most welcome.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test.info file

```
    name = configure test
    description = configure test.
    core = 7.x
    ; NEW LINE
    configure = admin/config/test
```

test.module file

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function test_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'description' => 'Configuration for test module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('test_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
?>
```

Comment: I had the hook_menu already. I just forgot how to insert the configure page. And I'm so used to hooks that I was looking form something more complicated that the configure line in the .info file. Thank You.